# HTML5 Form and PHP mail() Injection

Tags: php, html, email, csrf, code-injection

I have an HTML page with a simple form.
The form has an email input type that is required and a submit button.
I only need to send the emails somewhere. Like a subscribe button.

I am using the PHP `mail()` function to send the emails to my personal email address.

```
mail($to, $subject, $message, $additional_headers);
```

Do you think I could have any problems in this situation? Should I use PHP Mailer instead?

I read about email injection, but as I tested the form, I couldn't see any problems. I think the email type of HTML5 doesn't let you to insert any other characters to spam the field.

I'm going to use CAPTCHA so that I won't be spammed with bots.
**Not going to use it anymore**

Sorry to post this, being so many (old) topics about Email Injection, but there is no one with HTML5. And if I'm right, I don't really need to test about email injection. I'm looking for a very simple and short code.

**EDIT:**

So I got too much help and I am really confused.
I only have a simple HTML page with an email input field. I want that email to be sent to my email.

So I don't need to use `htmlspecialchars()` because I only use the user's input for `$message` and `$headers`. I will use `preg_match( "/[\r\n]/", $_POST['email'])` to check for injecting extra fields (such as CC and BCC) into the header.

In my case, given the fact that I only use mail() function, can I get CSRF Attacks or any other attacks that I should be concerned ?

Comment: You are wrong already at the point where you expect that any request that reaches your server-side script must have come from your form – which of course it doesn’t. It doesn’t even have to come from anything that you would call a “browser” – _anything_ that is capable of making HTTP requests can bombard your script with _any_ data it likes. So parameter validation inside your server-side script is _always_ an absolute necessity.

Comment: @CBroe is correct -- you need to sanitize your input. Something as simple as running `htmlspecialchars()` on your `mail()` parameters before passing them is a great start.

Comment: Here is my suggestion, in addition to CBroe and kittykittybangbang Htmlsepcialchars sanitize your input and help prevent XSS injection attack, I suggest also you make a token to prevent CSRF attack. All at all try to read this guide line https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category:OWASP_Top_Ten_Project#tab=OWASP_Top_10_for_2013, and regarding your email service try to use API from Mandrill or Mailgun.org. Depending on how secure it should be you might also consult a web security expert.

Comment: Thank you : @CBroe ,kittykittybangbang and maytham. I will try to follow your tips. I thought that if the field doesn't allow to input something else than an email, it will be already secured. I will sanitize it to be sure. I'm using this as a guide for anti spam bots [link](http://nfriedly.com/techblog/2009/11/how-to-build-a-spam-free-contact-forms-without-captchas/) but what about human spam like sending and refreshing the page or just back and send again ? Can I make it secure without using captcha ? It looks better without..

Comment: How do you use the user provided data in the `mail` function parameters?

Comment: @Gumbo : I just need user's email into the `$message`. And that should be all. At this point I want to send it as an email.
`preg_match( "/[\r\n]/", $email )` I might use this to check for bot spam. In my case, if I use `htmlspecialchars()` it won't do much, because lines are not special in HTML.
And I just need to sanitize the `$headers`. What do you think ?

Answer (score -2):

To be sure that you get a safe message, you must apply some filtres:

```
<?php
$message = strip_tags( $message ); 
$subject = strip_tags( $subject );
mail($to, $subject, $message, $additional_headers);
```

Comment: This does not fix header injection at *all*. OP needs to show us how he's actually using the code. Also, use `htmlentities` instead, as that won't delete characters.